# Ignoring whitespace when adding to char array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm doing a school exercise where the user inputs a string and the program must check if it's a palindrome. My only problem currently is that I can't get the loop to ignore whitespaces included in the input string.

```
Console.Write("Insert string: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] charArray = new char[input.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(input, i))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        charArray[i] += input[i];
    }
}
string original = new string(charArray);
```

I've seemingly tried everything I know, but the whitespaces just get added to the array no matter what I try. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: what's the status of this question? if one solved it, then it should be used to be marked as solved for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] Ok you can try the replace method which replaces what you provide with what you want instead (space into no space)

```
string str = "This is a test";
str = str.Replace(" ", "");
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about _any_ whitespace - not just at the start and end. Palindromes ignore whitespace.

Comment: If I understood correctly, Trim() only trims the whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string, not any whitespace between words in that string, so sadly it doesn't help me with this one.

Comment: Also, strings are immutable, so you'd want to assign the return value of `Trim()` to something - `input = input.Trim();` for instance

Comment: Alright you just got a bunch of answers! Choose your poison as they say

Answer (score 0):

How about using the framework and going this route:

```
char[] charArray = input.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work ?

```
Console.Write("Insert string: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] charArray = input.Where(character => !Char.IsWhitespace(character)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

When a whitespace is encountered, you never update the value at its position and so it remains a whitespace. So, write to a new array/string:

```
var newString = string.Empty;

for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i]))
    {
        newString += input[i];
    }
}
```

or something more like your code:

```
Console.Write("Insert string: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] charArray = new char[input.Length];
var newString = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(input, i))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        newString += input[i];
    }
 }
Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Comment: It's better to use StringBuilder than append to a string in a loop. Otherwise, performance will suffer significantly once the string becomes large.